# jquery datatables : Fix table heading and allow scrolling of records in the body

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am using the jquery datatables to display the data dynamically. In some cases the records seems to be so long and I wanted to fix the table heading and able to scroll through the rest of records.

```
<a href="https://jsfiddle.net/Bhannur/q7d2j0z3/2"> Sample</a>
```

Below is the link for JSFiddle and it works fine with CSS code(commented).

[Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/Bhannur/q7d2j0z3/2/)

In my project scenario, I want to fix the issue by change of Javascript datatable properties.

Comment: You didn't provide the link as you stated.

Comment: @jhpratt They have (click on the [edit] link to see) - I won't help to show it because OP need to create a [mcve] in the question body

Comment: updating the link.

Answer (score 1):

The Fixed header extension for DataTables will help you:
https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/

**From DataTables.net**

> When displaying tables with a particularly large amount of data shown
>   on each page, it can be useful to have the table's header and / or
>   footer fixed to the top or bottom of the scrolling window. This lets
>   your users quickly determine what each column refers to rather than
>   needing to scroll back to the top of the table.

**Example:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.3/css/fixedHeader.dataTables.min.css">
<script src=https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.3/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js' />
$('#myTable').DataTable( {
    fixedHeader: true
} );
```

**EDIT:** Working Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/q7d2j0z3/8/)

Your script references are incorrect. Follow the ones I have on the fiddle.
[image: It should look like this]

Comment: I have tried the same in the fiddle code. https://jsfiddle.net/Bhannur/q7d2j0z3/5/ . It is not working. please check and let me know if I am missing something..

Comment: Updated the answer, please mark as 'correct' when your solution works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need scrollY with scrollCollapse and paging properties like this, see [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5psajqxr/) for demo.

I added some other properties to make it look like the demo you have, the properties itself are pretty much self explanatory but tell me if you don't understand anything.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#list').DataTable({
    "scrollY": "200px",
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "paging": false,
    "searching": false,
    "info": false,
    "ordering": false
  });
});
```